# Java - Selecting and moving an object

Tags: java

I want to basically select an object on the frame and then drag it and the object moves with the mouse. For some reason I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my code pressed method :

```
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
 {
    //Get x and y
    int x = event.getX();
    int y = event.getY();
    //set selected to null
    selected = null;
    //if a fruit contains x, y then selected is assigned that fruit
    for( Fruit m : fruits)
        {
        if(m.contains(x,y))
            {
            selected.setXY(x,y);
            }
        }
```

This is my drag method:

```
 public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event)
 {
     //if selected not equal null
     if(selected != null){
        //get x and y
        int x = event.getX();
        int y = event.getY();
        //make select follow the mouse and repaint
        selected.setXY(x,y);
        repaint();
   }
  }
```

If you need more of my code, please let me know and I will edit the question and add it.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You set selected to `null` and then try to call its `setXY` method. Won't it raise a `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you set selected to null it cannot work.

What happens if you change mousePressed to (note that it will only work if there is only one fruit at (x,y):

```
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
 {
    //Get x and y
    int x = event.getX();
    int y = event.getY();
    //set selected to null
    selected = null;
    //if a fruit contains x, y then selected is assigned that fruit
    for( Fruit m : fruits)
    {
       if(m.contains(x,y))
       {
         selected = m;
         // position is set in mouseDrag
       }
    }
```

In mouseReleased you then set selected back to null (optional).

Comment: I have multiple fruits on the frame, how would I drop one fruit and then drag another fruit on the same frame

Comment: As long as you don't have more than one fruit at the position of the click it shoud work. If there is more than one you will drag one of the fruits (the last one that contains x,y).

Comment: for some reason its only moving one fruit and it the same one every time

Comment: Put a System.out.println("m: "+m); after "if(m.contains(x,y)){ " to see which element is getting selected.